# How to see all the image in a header - CSS

Tags: image, css

I want to know how I can see the 100% of a picture in a header with CSS. The problem is that when I add the image to the header, the image does not resize, so I have to make bigger the header, but I don't want that.

```
.header{
  background-image: url("../IMAGES/myimage.png");
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Basically I want to achieve a header with an image resized, so I will be able to see the full image in a header with the dimensions that I want on the header. I am new in CSS. Feel free to ask any question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how I can see the 100% of a picture in a header with CSS

to see a **background image** in it's entirety, use

```
background-size: contain;
```

```css
.header{
  background-image: url("//placehold.it/300x100/cf5");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;     /* add this to not repeat it as pattern */
  background-position: 50% 50%;     /* center it? */
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
```

than id needed you can additionally play with `background-position` to set it's position

If you want the image to **fill the entire header area** without distortions use

```
background-size: cover;
```

```css
.header{
  background-image: url("//placehold.it/300x100/cf5");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;     /* add this to not repeat it as pattern */
  background-position: 50% 50%;     /* center it? */
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
```

if you don't care that the image distorts but you want the image to stretch-to-fill than use

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

```css
.header{
  background-image: url("//placehold.it/300x100/cf5");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
```

Comment: It works but the image it repeats inside the header. How can I make it without repeat the image?

Comment: @AdrianRodriguez see my edit (set `background-repeat: no-repeat;`)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Without exactly knowing what you really want to achieve, I think you're trying to do, what the [background-size property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) does.

With `background-size: cover;` you can force the background image to cover the whole area of the according element (like a `div`).

Your code example would look like

```
.header{
  background-image: url("../IMAGES/myimage.png");
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use:

```
max-width: 100%;
```

On the css of the image, that will make it be at max, the 100% of the width of the container.

**CLARIFICATION**

For an image inside the container header, max-width will do the trick. If it's a background image, background-size:contain will maintain the image INSIDE the header, while cover will expand the image to cover the whole header.

```css
.header > img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  width: 600px;
}

.header2 {
  background-image: url("https://source.unsplash.com/random/500x500");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat-x: no-repeat;
  height: 200px;
  width: 600px;
}

.header3 {
  background-image: url("https://source.unsplash.com/random/500x500");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 200px;
  width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  This is my header
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/500x500" alt="and this is my image inside it" />
</div>

<div class="header2">
  This is my second header with a background contained inside
</div>

<div class="header3">
  This is my third header with a background covering it
</div>
```

Comment: Like this?  `.header{
 background-image: url("../IMAGES/myimage.png");
 max-width: 100%;
 height: 100px;
}`

Comment: max-width is if you're trying to show an image on the header. If you're trying to show a background on it, use `background-size: contain` so it will be "contained" inside the parent element